# How to send messages from one app to another

Tags: java, android, messaging

I'd just like to know how to:

1. Specify what app options will show in "app chooser" intent activity (ex. Have it only show apps that have a messaging feature)
2. how to transfer/display messages(email, text, DM, etc.) from one app to another?

Is it even possible? What api's/classes would I need to use/research? Would I have to write the code in another language and transfer it over? I'm currently working in android using java.

Comment: What does "have a messenger feature" mean? Do Web browsers count? Email clients? How about apps with a customer support chat feature? How would you determine whether an arbitrary app has "a messaging feature" or not? Similarly, what does "access the messaging feature" mean? And what does "display its data" mean?

Comment: Why are you thinking about using another language? Are you needing a web service? That's language agnostic, practically, and not tied to Android

Answer (score 1):

The list of options depend on the Intenet type you set. Following are the intent types you might use -

```
myIntent.setType(String mimeType)

image/jpeg
audio/mpeg4-generic
text/html
audio/mpeg
audio/aac
audio/wav
audio/ogg
audio/midi
audio/x-ms-wma
video/mp4
video/x-msvideo
video/x-ms-wmv
image/png
image/jpeg
image/gif
.xml ->text/xml
.txt -> text/plain
.cfg -> text/plain
.csv -> text/plain
.conf -> text/plain
.rc -> text/plain
.htm -> text/html
.html -> text/html
.pdf -> application/pdf
.apk -> application/vnd.android.package-archive
```

Refer to intent documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

Answer (score -1):

I think maybe this is what you are looking for.

[Send Simple Data to Other Apps](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html)

Here is an example in the documentation.

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)));
```